# How can I stop the integration of NDSolve with a condition?

Tags: equation-solving, differential-equations

I try to solve a partial differential equation by `NDSolve`. At some point, I want to stop the integrating by a condition that compares the min value of the function with a threshold. I tried to use `StopIntegration` in the `WhenEvent`, and tried using `NMinimize` to find the min value of the function. But it does not seem stop the evaluation. From the warning message, I think the conditions of `NMinimize[h[x, t], {x, t}] <= 0.01` I set for `whenevent` may be wrong. Could someone explain to me what is going on? How could I handle this problem? Is there any better or simpler way to do that?

```
mdfun = First[h /. NDSolve[{D[h[x, t], t] + D[h[x, t]^-1*D[h[x, t], x], x] + 
   D[h[x, t]^3*D[h[x, t], {x, 3}], x] == 0, 
 h[0, t] == h[2 Sqrt[2] \[Pi], t], 
 h[x, 0] == 1 + 1/10*Sin[x/Sqrt[2]], 
 WhenEvent[NMinimize[h[x, t], {x, t}] <= 0.01, 
  "StopIntegration"]}, h, {x, 0, 2 Sqrt[2] \[Pi]}, {t, 0, 10}, 
StepMonitor :> Print[t]]]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, at first you don't solve your equation properly, the grid spacing is not enough for the entire time range. So first increase resolution, e.g.:

```
tmax = 10;
mdfun = NDSolveValue[
  {D[h[x, t], t] + D[h[x, t]^-1*D[h[x, t], x], x] + D[h[x, t]^3*D[h[x, t], {x, 3}], x] == 0,
   h[0, t] == h[2 Sqrt[2] \[Pi], t], h[x, 0] == 1 + 1/10*Sin[x/Sqrt[2]]},
   h, {x, 0, 2 Sqrt[2] \[Pi]}, {t, 0, tmax},
   AccuracyGoal -> 2, PrecisionGoal -> 2,
   Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
     "MinPoints" -> 3000, "MaxPoints" -> 3000}}];
```

Then you can get nice solution:

```
Plot[mdfun[x, #] & /@ Range[0, tmax, 1] // Evaluate, {x, 0, 2 Sqrt[2] \[Pi]},
  PlotRange -> {0, 1.5}, PlotStyle -> Opacity /@ (Range[0, tmax, 1]/tmax)]
```

[image]

now you see that the event h<0.01 is never achived.

Secondly, NMinimize returns value in form {value, {x,y}}, so you should use `NMinimize[..][[1]]`. The other point you should properly specify the range of your variables for NMinimize like this (.6 - just some arb. limit):

```
NMinimize[{mdfun[a, b], 0 < a < 2 Sqrt[2] \[Pi], 0 < b < t}, {a, b}][[1]] < .6
```

Now the whole thing works, but very slow. I would suggest to make condition simply for point, where the min is located. find the minimum with previus solution:

```
xmin = x /. Minimize[{mdfun[x, t], 0 < x < 2 Sqrt[2] \[Pi], 0 < t < tmax}, {x, t}][[2]]
```

and rewrite whenevent:

```
WhenEvent[h[xmin, t] < .4, "StopIntegration"]
```

Then it will work much faster.

Comment: Hi,@funnypony! I adopted your suggestions except for grid spacing for faster here I set it is 300. I do think your advice is correct. Actually, I don't know the exact position where the min-value is located, the eqn. in my post just makes the issue simpler. Thus, I still use `WhenEvent` with `NMinimize`. But when I run it, MMA spits a stack of warning message. However, it still returns a result, when I plot it, I find WhenEvent doesn't work because the solution contains obviously value which is less than 0.6. Pls see the following code :)

Comment: `tmax = 10; mdfun = First[   h /. NDSolve[{D[h[x, t], t] + D[h[x, t]^-1*D[h[x, t], x], x] +         D[h[x, t]^3*D[h[x, t], {x, 3}], x] == 0,       h[0, t] == h[2 Sqrt[2] \[Pi], t],       h[x, 0] == 1 + 1/10*Sin[x/Sqrt[2]],       WhenEvent[       NMinimize[{mdfun[x, t], 0 < x < 2 Sqrt[2] \[Pi],            0 < t < tmax}, {x, t}][[1]] < 0.6, "StopIntegration"]},      h, {x, 0, 2 Sqrt[2] \[Pi]}, {t, 0, tmax}, AccuracyGoal -> 2,      PrecisionGoal -> 2,      Method -> {"MethodOfLines",        "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid",          "MinPoints" -> 300, "MaxPoints" -> 300}}]]`

Comment: lxy, please look once again how i wrote whenevent - with a and b instead of x and t. x and t are ndsolve variables and better avoid inserting them in numerical functions. The other point - you search for min at each integration step, so at any time the boundary for this variable is not tmax but t. write it this way: NMinimize[{mdfun[a, b], 0 < a < 2 Sqrt[2] \[Pi], 0 < b < t}, {a, b}][[1]] < .6 and it will work, but slow..

Comment: Thanks @funnypony, it does work now. Thanks for your helpful suggestions!